# Menu desplegable en react

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo mis primeros pasos en react, estoy practicando con un menu desplegable que estaria en un sidebar lateral en una vista de escritorio. En el codigo que tengo traigo los titulos de cada seccion de un json, tambien adentro tengo varios ul, que a su vez contienen li y adentro etiquetas Link para las rutas.

Lo que pude lograr hasta el momento es que al hacer el onClick se despliegue cada vez que clickeo alguna de las secciones, si vuelvo a clickear la seccion que toque con anterioridad se cierra, ya que simplemente uso un toggle y un css basico de display none y display block...

Pero como comentaba no es mi idea ese funcionamiento, yo quiero que al por ejemplo clickear alguna seccion se cierren todas las demas si es que hubiera alguna abierta.

Paso el codigo, muchas gracias. saludos.

```
const Topic = ({ language, title,id}) => {
  
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false)
  

 
  const handleClick = () => {
    const changeLanguage = titles.filter(el => el.id === id && setValue(!value))
    
    return changeLanguage
  }
<nav>
      {size ? (
        <TopicTitle>{language}</TopicTitle>
      ) : (
        <ButtonLang handleClick={handleClick} language={language}/>
      )}
      {title.map((el) => (
        <SingleTitle key={el}  value={value} language={language} el={el} />
      ))}
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Topic;
```

Comment: Hola  podrías agregar más código o alguna imagen que pueda ayudar a entender mejor lo que deseas?

Comment: https://reactjsexample.com/get-data-from-json-file-and-display-simple-form-menu/

Comment: https://reactjsexample.com/get-data-from-json-file-and-display-simple-form-menu/  . Si podes fijate en esa pagina, pero la idea no es igual a como se ve en la imagen de la pagina, sino que sin tener que apretar el boton de la seccion abierta, si decido ver otra seccion se cierre la abierta anteriormente y me abra la que estoy queriendo ver actualmente.

Comment: hola, mmm podrias usar ese evento que dispare la funcion, a eso te refieres? `onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter}`  `onMouseLeave={this.mouseLeave}`

Answer (score 0):

ok gracias por su ayuda, ya lo hice funcionar, lo central para no tener que abrumar a nadie leyendo codigo, si es que quisiera una respuesta rapida, es lo siguiente, crear un estado con valor nulo, hacer una funcion manejadora del click con una condicion, comparando el estado con un id, si se cumple cambiar el estado a nulo...como en un principio no se cumple se almacena en el estado de id. Despues se usa ternario dentro de lo que devuelve el jsx para saber si el estado es igual al indice, si lo fuera se pasa lo que hubiera dentro del menu, y sino es nulo, eso es todo. dejo esto explicado abajo. Muchas gracias.

```
const Navbar = () => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

  const handleOnClick = (id) => {
    if (selected === id) {
      return setSelected(null);
    }
    setSelected(id);
  };
```

lo que retorno en jsx, en si varia segun que quieran tener dentro del menu. Tambien podria hacerse con clases en lugar del ternario.

```
) : selected === id ? (
      <ul>
        {title.map((element) => (
          <SingleTopic
            element={element}
            language={language}
            key={element}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    ) : null}
```